# Is it possible to escape this str_replace() for path traversal?

Tags: php, replace, path, escaping, file-get-contents

I'm testing one of our PHP web applications for security issues.
The system the code is running on runs with at least PHP7.2.

Now I found something like the following in the code (simplified for this question, but boils down to this):

```php
$file = $_GET['file'];

$path = "/some/directory/" . $file;

$path = str_replace(['../', '..'], '', $path);

echo file_get_contents($path);
```

Is it possible to modify the file parameter in a way that we can escape `/some/directory`, so that after the `str_replace()` the `file_get_contents()`-call looks something like: `file_get_contents(/some/directory/../../etc/passwd)`?

Edit:
I can't change the order of code execution. I can only define the value of `$_GET['file']` with my request.
Furthermore I know how to make this more secure but for my research I intend to break it.

Basically what needs to be done is somehow tricking out the `str_replace()` into leaving some `../` behind.

I tried for a few hours now, with various approaches, but - luckily for our application - couldn't get it working.
Do you have any ideas?

You can fiddle around with the code here: https://3v4l.org/3ehYA

Comment: apply str_replace on $file  first and than concate ith '/some/directory/'

Comment: or can you give and example to explain more please

Comment: `$file = $_GET['file'];` this needs filtering first.

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI I edited my question. I can't change the order of code execution. I can only define the value of $_GET['file'] with my request.

Comment: Ok , so let's me know if i don't say something wrong , you want to modify the $path and don't apply changes on the "/some/directory/" that exist in the string ? if that true ? another question . is allways you will have "/some/directory/" or may be another thing to know the delimiter from where to start str_replacing?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI Yes that's kinda true. I only want to change  `$_GET['file']`/`$file` so that after the `str_replace()` the `file_get_contents()` returns something from a directory above `/some/directory/` (e.g: /etc/passwd).  There will always be some path to a folder in front of the string.